# Helper array inside parent_construct() causes T_VARIABLE codeigniter 3.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

As answered by @bostaf in the post [loading configuration information in to the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597261/loading-configuration-information-in-to-the-library);

```
Unexpected T_VARIABLE is a parse error, 
meaning that code syntax or structure is not valid. 
This error usually occurs because of missing semicolon or bracket
somewhere before it's triggered.
```

**THIS** (sic!), I understand implicitly. I have also consulted every test-case listed under the **T_VARIABLE** primer in [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092267#18092267) as well as browsed intently through any and all related questions in the sidebar, but I have a feeling it's either so simple I'm just missing it, or there's something else at play. The error message: `Message: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)` - the source of the error;

```
     class Upload extends CI_Controller
     {
        function __construct()
        {    
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->database();
           $this->load->library(array('session','ion_auth'));
           $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));    //error line HERE
           $this->load->model('User_profile_model', 'User_profile', TRUE);
        }
    }
```

**THIS** coding shouldn't be erroring whatsoever as I have the same opening on several pages of this app (had an `unexpected '   function' (T_VARIABLE)` before due to the line space between the class declaration and function __construct() line) and **none** of the stated **T_VARIABLE** errors exist;

1) Missing semicolon/braces: **ALL** loaders lines terminate with the required semi-colon (and there are only two brackets for the `function __construct()`).

2) String concatenation: Not using `.` anywhere, so that's not an issue.

3) Missing expression operators: No expressions/regexes used, so no issue there.

4) Lists: Using arrays for libraries and helpers, but CI docs say I'm good for that particular formatting, and I've triple-checked this aspect.

5) Class Declarations: No, no...no probs there.

6) Variables after identifiers and 7) Missing parens after language constructs
 have no play (unless I went blind and missed something **COMPLETELY** obvious...

I really have no ken of what the actual issue could be as this exact codeblock starts numerous pages, and I've rechecked the ones that do to no effect. Like I said, it's super-clear and I'm missing it, or there may be another factor at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obviously...**, if you have code fragments meant to refer to a future event within the db (the posting of an `image_path` to an empty table column created for the occasion), you're going to error out all over the place - framework cain't be blamed (lol!). I'm going to just honestly resolve this as highly-informed confusion. The problem I'm having isn't actually related to syntactical erroring as much as getting tripped up by coding from another (intertwined) codebank known as **Ion Auth**. The error actually came from the initialization of the user id (`$id` or alternatively `$user->id`), so that original, earlier assessment that I started the post off with was **INDEED** factually positive. In the `user_profile_view` page, I had to move a misplaced `$user` variable declaration to right after the start of the `form_open` to finally have this error disappear. I thank anyone that took the time to read this and come away with anything.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->load->model('user_profile_model');
```

with lowercase

Comment: Thanks for your eyes @lpz , but the docs say I'm good for that model loader as is, and I use the same notation throughout my app to no ill effect - just to confirm that, I tried your line. Appreciate your time.